# What’s the safest long-term hardware wallet solution?

Tags: transactions, wallet, security

Looking for safest hardware wallet solution, for long time storage. Thanks!

Comment: It really depends on what "safe" means to you.  Different hardware wallets cater to different ideas about what safe means.  However, most safety concerns are centered around user behavior rather than the hardware they use.  In any case, keeping secret information using hardware is not specific enough to Bitcoin for me to agree that this question belongs here.

Answer (score 1):

This is my opinion because "safest" can be different for other people. Available hardware wallets that most of the Bitcoin users prefer using for long term (I have sorted them based on security):

1. Coldcard
2. Trezor
3. Bitbox
4. Jade

Although all these hardware wallets are secure, coldcard is at top because it's only used for bitcoin, tried and tested for long time now with active development.

Also check [Cypherock](https://cypherock.com) which was selected as one of the innovative infosec projects by [Nullcon](https://twitter.com/nullcon/status/1239550747114528768)